# iOS Contained View Controller Caused Auto layout Issues

Tags: ios, autolayout, viewcontroller

I'm working on a project with a fairly complicated layout that I've developed programatically. The main view consists of 7 different sized views placed vertically with 6 spacer views in-between. All of the spacer views are constrained to be equally tall. According to a loop I'm doing with view.hasAmbiguousLayout, none of my views are ambiguous. I've been extra careful in checking all of the constraints, and the view acts as I expect on different device sizes.

The strange bit happens when I add a contained view controller. I've been using a contained view controller to manage a popup view. This subview has some transparency so I can see the main view below it. If this secondary view has any subviews at all, the main view's layout changes ever so slightly. The moment I add it some of the bottom views move slightly upward.

Is there a cause for this that I am missing or could it just be a bug in ios? (The same thing happens when I build the layout in interface builder)

Comment: Does it appear to be a half-point flickering which happens while the secondary views are scrolled or moved?

Comment: No, the movement is multiple pixels and the secondary view is stationary. It happens as soon as I add it.

Comment: Try calling _ autolayoutTrace in the debugger once your view has been presented, it will give you a full trace from the whole window instead of having to loop. It does sound like an ambiguity issue

Comment: I tried calling _autolayoutTrace in multiple different places and after a delay. The results show that the two _UILayoutGuide's are ambiguous but the rest of the view is fine.